# How to keep css in html emails designed by SendGrid

Tags: css, email, html-email, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

i am getting an issue when design email template in the SendGrid.
I used css inline, i want to subText max 3 line.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tqgU.png)
Look good in the design, but when received email, 3 properties -webkit auto removed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYXF1.png)
it only keep be 2 properties.
help me, thank you

Comment: Different email clients will strip out different CSS rules. See https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and https://www.caniemail.com/

Comment: Never ever use `image` for your code. There is a very nice tool called `code snippet`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following on Litmus:

```
<div style="width:300px;overflow:hidden;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp:3;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
</div>
```

This worked only on Apple Mail, iPhones, and Samsung mail (Android).

You can use overflow:hidden with a max-height, and that will work with everything except MS Outlook Desktop (Windows). There is no fix for that, since it doesn't support overflow or max-height or anything (it supports a bit less than HTML4).

```
<div style="max-height:60px;overflow:hidden;width:300px;line-height:20px;">
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
</div>
```

What I've done here is calculated what the height of 3 lines would be (line-height of 20px * 3 = 60px), and used that as the height of a wrapping div.

Max-height is needed for Gmail iOS, which changes height:60px into height:auto.

Comment: thank you so much. i think it's best setup a div with a height same your way.